# How to merge two xmllistcollection in Flex 3

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

How to merge two xmllistcollection in Flex 3. Please note, addAll method is not available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this method.

```
private function mergeXLC(x1:XMLListCollection,x2:XMLListCollection):XMLListCollection
{
    return new XMLListCollection(x1.copy()+x2.copy());
}
```